# Existence and uniqueness of the equivalence closure

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Given a relation $R \subseteq B \times B $, show the existence and uniqueness of the closure of R under the properties that define an equivalence relation. Does the order in which the closures of these properties is produced matter?

My initial attempt:

Let us generate a candidate $S$ by obtaining the transitive closure of the symmetric closure of the reflexive closure. By applying the definition of symmetric closure on the reflexive closure we have that: $A = (Id_{B} \cup R) \cup (Id_{B} \cup R)^{-1}$. By the property of the inverse relation of the union of relations, we have that $(Id_{B} \cup R) \cup (Id_{B} \cup R)^{-1} = (Id_{B} \cup R) \cup (Id_{B}^{-1} \cup R^{-1}) = Id_{B} \cup R \cup R^{-1} $. Now, applying the definition of transitive closure onto A, we have that $$S = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N^{+}} } (Id_{B} \cup R \cup R^{-1})^{k} $$. How do I demonstrate that this relation is indeed the equivalence closure, in the sense that it exists and is unique?

Comment: I would prefer thinking of this and gaining intuition by looking at it from a graph theoretic perspective.  Imagine creating your directed multigraph corresponding to your original relation (*draw a vertex for each element in $B$, draw an arrow from one vertex to another iff the corresponding first and second elements are related*).  Recognize that the equivalence closure of the relation is very simply the relation asking if two vertices belong to the same [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Comment: I don't really know where to go from here

Comment: You’ve already done most of the work. The closure is the smallest relation containing $R$ that is an equivalence relation. Well, to be reflexive it must contain $Id_B$. To be symmetric it must contain your next expression, and to be transitive your last. Now you just need to show that your final expression defines an equivalence relation. Transitivity is obvious, and reflexivity and symmetry are both not hard.